# Why are porn films called blue films?

Tags: terminology, adult-movies

Adult films — i.e. porn films — are also called blue films. But why are they called that?

Comment: Yes, red films would be more sensible name.

Comment: It depends on where you are.  In China they're yellow.

Comment: I believe the Japanese call them "pink films".

Comment: Called blue films by whom?

Comment: Of possible interest to readers of this question are the answers (including mine) on the English Language & Usage site to the essentially identical question, "[What is the origin of the term 'blue movie'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605875/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-blue-movie)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[It's unknown](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blue+movie):

> Why off-color movies were called “blue” remains a matter of
>   conjecture. **Although one definition of “blue” has been “lewd” since
>   the 19th century, its application to movies might have referred to the
>   19th-century Blue Laws morality codes and state and local laws based
>   on them**, of which dirty movies would certain run afoul.
>
> Other
>   explanations include the bluish tint of the early cheaply made
>   black-andwhite movies, and the bluish cigarette and cigar smoke haze
>   in rooms where men gathered to watch such films (the get-togethers
>   were in fact known as “smokers”).
>
> “Blue” faded over the years and was
>   replaced by “dirty movie, “adult film,” “skin flick” and “hard- or
>   soft-core porn.”

[This blog post](https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2015/05/21/sacre-bleu/) looks at the use of "blue" in this context:

> **Nobody really knows**, as it turns out. The origin of blue in the sense
>   of lewd, coarse, or pornographic has been tough to pin down:
>   etymologists have put forward a bunch of theories but haven’t found
>   anything conclusive.

The [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) has [a question about the term "off-color"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/115999/91509) where some of the answers also refer to "blue".

Comment: In France, adult films are also called "films roses" (english translation: *pink films*).

Comment: "blue" is still in current use to describe [stand-up comedy with dirty jokes and/or swearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribaldry).  e.g. "I don't work blue".